# Android Room - Returning last 30 days (1 month) - java

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room

I am complete beginner in Android development and got stuck with a fairly simple problem (I guess ;) ).

I am trying to retrieve records from SQLite (using Room) for last 30 days.

This is my query which does not work - it does not return any records (from @Dao Class):

```
 // getting fares for one day (custom-made query)
@Query("SELECT * FROM fare WHERE createdDateDb >=datetime('now', 'now', '-30 day')")
public List<Fare> getFaresOneDay();
```

However, this simple query which retrieves all of the records without specified dates does work:

```
 // getting all fare (via custom-made query)
@Query("SELECT * FROM fare ORDER BY createdDateDb DESC")
public List<Fare> getAllFares();
```

This is my DateTypeConverter class:

```
public class DateTypeConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    public long convertDateToLong(Date date) {
        return date.getTime();
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public Date convertLongToDate(long time) {
        return new Date(time);
    }

}
```

This is how the value is being assigned to createdDateDb (before it is being inserted into DB):

```
fare.setCreatedDateDb(new Date());
```

This is my 'Entity' class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "fare")
public class Fare {
    private String fareValue;
    private String typeOfJob;

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @NonNull
    private Integer jobId;

    // dates used for user display
    private String createdDate;
    private String createdTime;

    // date var used for comparisons - not to be displayed for the user
    private Date createdDateDb;
}
```

and also setter and getter for createdDateDb

```
// #6 createdDateDb getter
public Date getCreatedDateDb() {
    return createdDateDb;
}

// #6 createdDateDb setter
public void setCreatedDateDb(Date createdDateDb) {this.createdDateDb = createdDateDb; }
```

I would really appreciate some hints how to approach it, as it feels like I'm getting nowhere.
I have also tried the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM fare 
WHERE createdDateDb BETWEEN datetime('now', 'start of month') AND datetime('now', 'localtime')
```

Unfortunately it did not work either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, but I was trying to get registers from 1 year ago and by the time I searched for solutions I found this post. I solved like this

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE CAST(my_date/1000 AS LONG) >= strftime('%s', 'now', '-12 month')
```

storing data using calendar.getTime() (as milisseconds)

explanation:

as strftime function returns the value of SECONDS I had to divide my milisseconds value by 1000 and cast it to long as sql returns the result of the division as an INTEGER, and then it works properly

Answer (score 1):

Use `DATE` SQLITE FUNCTION

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM fare WHERE createdDateDb >= DATE('now', '-30 day')")
```

Comment: In this case you would not always get the last 30 days, but `dateadd` is the way to go

Comment: Thanks Michael for your input, but as I mentioned in the other comment answering Mihai's post - this solution did not work either. When I remove 'WHERE createdDateDb >=DATE('now', '-30 day')") from the query - it returns all of the records as expected. Is it possible it is something to do with how the date is being stored in createdDateDb or some mistake in DateTypeConverter? I'm stuck on this one ;). Thanks so far for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
datetime('now', 'now', '-30 day')
```

This one above returns null,use it correctly

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM fare WHERE createdDateDb >=datetime('now', '-30 day')")
```

Comment: I have tried this too, and no results are returned from database. I have checked the code again - to see if there is some random mistake - with no luck, but when I change the query to the same one as posted in my first post: getAllFares() - that method works. Any more suggestions how I can find out where the problem is and fix it? Thanks guys for your help so far - I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I found what was causing the query not to work as intended - the format of the Date stored in createdDateDb, namely if let's assume we were adding the fare now it would be saved in the following way:
Wed Aug 29 16:48:55 GMT +01:00 2018

When I changed pattern of how Date is stored in createdDateDb to (yyyy-MM-dd) - Query magically works as expected ;).

```
            Date c = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String formattedDate = sdf.format(c);
```

Thanks a lot guys for your help - I really appreciate it!

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 0):

For future people searching for the answer, here is my solution:
`(strftime('%s','now') - createdDateDb) < CAST(strftime('%s','1970-01-30') AS INTEGER)`
in the `WHERE` clause